# Deep scratches on the core of transformer

Tags: transformer, core

The top and one side of my transformer have a few deep scratches which penetrate the laminate protection and short some of the core sheets. Are there any consquences to that?

Comment: your core may get hotter from eddy currents, and your efficiency may go down for the same reason.

Comment: Depending on the location of the short it may have little or no effect.  What matters is that no large loops are created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes when the transformer is assembled, they make side grooves and then weld those grooves with a MIG. So, shorting laminates on the surface won't make  any difference.